# Is it bad practice to use iFrames on many websites so clients can use our purchase forms?

Tags: php, forms, iframe

In one facet of our business, we offer individuals the ability to sell products and services through our website while using a unique identifier to provide those individuals with credit. While this has been very beneficial for us so far, we have been discussing the idea of a generic form/site in which our sales reps could implement on their existing sites and all the processing would take place on our end.

The initial idea (and really only way we can think of doing it), is to build the sample form/site with some basic restraints (600px wide, etc) and providing instructions for our reps to include on their sites using an iFrame on their page or even using something like a colorbox modal window.

The potential issues I see with this currently are:

1) It may cause https conflicts given their site will obviously sit on one domain but all pages would be pulled and PHP Session data would be stored on our domain within the iframe.

2) We collect payment information at the end of a purchase (collecting banking information for ACH transactions or credit card via PayPal Express checkout). This may cause page conflicts on redirects as well as wanting to make sure the sales reps cannot scrape this information as it is entered on "their" site.

I am not really sure there is another way to do this besides using iFrames (putting our actual source code available on the 600+ sales reps sites is not feasible) but am curious if others have implemented similar projects or if there are suggestions for a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow the same *way* of Google Search, for example. Let your clients free to use whatever they want as container and provide an API to include your HTML code. Take a look at: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/getting_started.html